# Function to translate from two 90 deg shifted triangle waves to a rotation angle?

Tags: functions, transformation

I have a [dual output endless rotary encoder](http://www.taiwanalpha.com/downloads?target=products&id=79) that varies it's analogue outputs as two triangle wave with a 90 degree phase shift between A and B (see graph below). Can anybody suggest an appropriate transform/function

> f(a,b)=angle

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. What are the requirements for this function? You say "f(a,b) = angle", but what angle?

Comment: If you want a function that looks something like the A graph, for example, you could try something like
$$
f(x) = 90-\left| (x \mod{180}) - 90 \right|
$$
This doesn't give exactly the graph in the picture, but you can tweak the numerical values.

Comment: a,b both range between 0 and 100% (left axis of graph) and the two of them together uniquely encode the angle of rotation (bottom axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a,b \in [0,1]$:

$$f(a,b) = \begin{cases} 180a &\text{if }b \geq \frac{1}{2}\\  180(2-a)&\text{if }b < \frac{1}{2}\end{cases}$$

(Alternatively, note that you can parametrically plot $\langle a(t), b(t)\rangle$ in two dimensions; it will make a diamond shape. You can recover the angle using trigonometry, though this is more work.)

Comment: thanks, it's going inside a micro controller interrupt handler so the non trig solution is much preferable...